# <h:form target="_blank" only after validation

Tags: java, jsf

I want a form that after submitting and validating opens a new tab with the results.  I used the `<h:form target="_blank"` method to get the new tab, but it shows the validation errors in the new tab.  I want it to only open the new tab if the validation is passed.

My guess is the only real cross browser solution would be to do some SJAX validation onsubmit, but I'm not sure if there are any libraries that will do this for me.

So, is there a way to validate and open a new window only if validation passes?

Comment: What triggers the validation? Can't you just use a `commandButton` or `commandLink` with `target="_blank"`? The new tab will be opened after the validation phase takes palce. Of course, you'll need to provide the data you want to show to the new page by using, for example, the "`flash` scope" (tough I don't know if it really is a scope at all, but people calls it that way).

Comment: There are two ways to do this: 1. Split your actual action into two, the first that only trigger the validation phase of the data and process nothing, when this action finishes make another call (using javascript) to a second action that performs the real work. 2. Split the action in two, the first handles validation and data process, then after it's execution invoke a second action that will only show the result by opening a new tab/window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code sample I assume you are using a `<h:form>` and a `<h:commandButton>` within it.

If so, you have to do a simple trick to overcome this issue. You have to use a `<a4j:commandButton>` instead of your `<h:commandButton>` and keep the `<h:commandButton>` hidden. Then use the `oncomplete` event of the `<a4j:commandButton>` to determine whether to `click` the `<h:commandButton>`.

The `<h:commandButton` is clicked by javascript, only if validations are passed.

```
<h:form target="_blank">
  <h:inputText value="" required="true" id="txt"/>
  <rich:message for="txt"/>
  <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.someMethod()}"           
    oncomplete="if(#{!(facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal ge 2)}){
    #{rich:element('btn')}.click();}"/>
  <h:commandButton value="temp" id="btn" style="display:none;"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: This isn't how I ended up solving it as I am using primefaces, but this is probably the most elegant solution I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

**If you can invoke the validation using JavaScript using some AJAX behavior**, you may be able to do it easily by using an `onSubmit` event function as below:

```
   function fnSubmit(){
     var validated= performValidation();
     if(validated){
         document.getElementById('formName').target="_blank";
         document.getElementById('formaName').submit();
     }
   }
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yeah this is why I started the answer with an `if`. Now a days, more and more AJAX is being used so thought this might be helpful.

Comment: Even with Ajax, that's not how JSF works. You can use an ajax tag to do what you're trying to say in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been inpired by this thread to found a solution for my problem. So I decided to post mine, too. I had the requirement to stay on the same site if an error occured and if not to open a new tab with a page for printing.

```
<h:form target="#{printBean.isErrorHappened() ? '_self' : '_blank'}"
     id="formPrintSearchResult">
     <h:commandLink id="cmdLinkPrintSearchResult"
          value="Print overview"
          onmouseover="#{rich:element('checkForErrors')}.click();"
          action="#{printController.printSearch()}" />
      <a4j:commandLink id="checkForErrors" style="display:none;" 
          render="formPrintSearchResult" />
</h:form>
```

If you like you could include another action on the a4j:commandLink to check for errors and set the errorHappened in the printBean.